# How can I detect whether an image is a PNG or APNG format?

Tags: php, python, ruby, perl, apng

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I programatically determine if a PNG is animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525152/can-i-programatically-determine-if-a-png-is-animated)

APNG is backwards compatible with PNG. I opened up an apng and png file in a hex editor and the first few bytes look identical. So if a user uploads either of these formats, how do I detect what the format really is? I've seen this done on some sites that block apng.

I'm guessing the ImageMagick library makes this easy, but what if I were to do the detect without the use of an image processing library (for learning purposes)? Can I look for specific bytes that tell me if the file is apng?

Solutions in any language is welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I programatically determine if a PNG is animated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525152/can-i-programatically-determine-if-a-png-is-animated), solution given is in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apng:

> Among users and maintainers of the PNG and MNG formats, APNG was not 
>   well received. In particular, PNG was conceived to be a single-image 
>   format [<sup>[2]</sup>](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Misc.html#Multiple-image-extension). APNG hides the subsequent frames in PNG ancillary chunks 
>   in such a way that APNG-unaware applications would ignore them, *but 
>   there are otherwise no changes to the format to allow software to 
>   distinguish between animated and non-animated images*. [italics mine]
>
> [2] ["PNG (Portable Network Graphics) Specification, Version 1.1#8.4. Multiple-image extension"](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Misc.html#Multiple-image-extension)

Answer (score 1):

See the solution of [Can I programatically determine if a PNG is animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525152/can-i-programatically-determine-if-a-png-is-animated/4525194#4525194): you could search for the string "acTL".

Answer (score 0):

APNG and PNG files' first few bytes' control can be bypass, easily . So this method isn't secure. User can change file's hex code and pass your this control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libmagic which is already installed on most Unix platforms.