# How do i detect APNG in python?

Tags: python, apng

APNG files dont have any clear way to detect them. For APNg unawware applications they appear as normal PNGs, and they will show the first screen. Detecting them is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNGs can be detected by seeing if the data contains a acTL block before a IDAT block.

this solution is adapted to python from this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4525194/5997749

```py
def is_apng(a: bytes):
    acTL = a.find(b"\x61\x63\x54\x4C")
    if acTL > 0: # find returns -1 if it cant find anything
        iDAT = a.find(b"\x49\x44\x41\x54")
        if acTL < iDAT:
            return True
    return False
```